# 77 is the greatest integer that cannot be a finite sum of distinct integers greater than 1 whose sum of their reciprocals is 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In 1963, Ron Graham proved on a short article entitled "A Theorem on Partitions" (it can be found in the web) that every positive integer greater than $ 77 $ is a finite sum of distinct integers greater than 1 such that the sum of their reciprocals equals 1.

Related: [Prove that $ x_1+ \dotsb + x_k=n, \frac1{x_1}+ \dotsb + \frac1{x_k}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622444/prove-that-x-1-dotsb-x-k-n-frac1x-1-dotsb-frac1x-k-1/622774#622774).

At the end of the article he says that D. H. Lehmer proved that $ 77 $ doesn't have this property, but hadn't published the proof at that time. On another Ron's article of 2008 or later he mention that result again and cite it as "D. H. Lehmer, (personal communication)".

Does anyone know how to prove it or where can I find a proof?

Thanks. Sorry for my english.

Comment: If it is a "personal communication" nothing but asking both persons involved, or a witness of that communication, will help.

Comment: To check if $n=77$ can be partitioned like this is a finite problem.

Comment: What's the largest integer conclusively proven not to have this property?

Answer (score 6):

This program gave a definitive check for all numbers up to $$104 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14.$$ As you can see, by that point there are multiple solutions. Also, no solutions for $...58,63,68,70, 72,77, \; $ but then success. Programming note: at first i added the reciprocals as double precision floats and accepted if within a very small error from $1.0$ Then I started to see sums that made me a little supicious, 0.9998 sort of thing, so i switched it to GMP and demanded that the sum of the product over each individual entry be the same as the product. No doubt that way. Note that, for those examples that work, the least common multiple od the numbers to be added is relatively small; I had the computer list that at the end of each line, less work for a human being to confirm one of these by hand (compared with the product).

```
   11         2    3    6     LCM  6
   24         2    4    6   12     LCM  12
   30         2    3   10   15     LCM  30
   31         2    4    5   20     LCM  20
   32         2    3    9   18     LCM  18
   37         2    3    8   24     LCM  24
   38         3    4    5    6   20     LCM  60
   43         2    4   10   12   15     LCM  60
   45         2    4    9   12   18     LCM  36
   45         2    5    6   12   20     LCM  60
   50         2    4    8   12   24     LCM  24
   50         3    4    6   10   12   15     LCM  60
   52         3    4    6    9   12   18     LCM  36
   53         2    5    6   10   30     LCM  30
   54         2    3    7   42     LCM  42
   55         2    4    7   14   28     LCM  28
   57         3    4    5   10   15   20     LCM  60
   57         3    4    6    8   12   24     LCM  24
   59         3    4    5    9   18   20     LCM  180
   60         2    6    9   10   15   18     LCM  90
   61         2    4    6   21   28     LCM  84
   62         2    4    6   20   30     LCM  60
   62         3    4    6    7   14   28     LCM  84
   64         2    4    8   10   40     LCM  40
   64         2    5   10   12   15   20     LCM  60
   64         3    4    5   10   12   30     LCM  60
   64         3    4    5    8   20   24     LCM  120
   65         2    6    8   10   15   24     LCM  120
   66         2    3   12   21   28     LCM  84
   66         2    4    6   18   36     LCM  36
   66         2    5    9   12   18   20     LCM  180
   67         2    3   12   20   30     LCM  60
   67         2    4    7   12   42     LCM  84
   67         2    5    6    9   45     LCM  90
   67         2    6    8    9   18   24     LCM  72
   69         2    3   14   15   35     LCM  210
   69         2    6    7   12   14   28     LCM  84
   71         2    3   11   22   33     LCM  66
   71         2    3   12   18   36     LCM  36
   71         2    5    8   12   20   24     LCM  120
   71         3    4    6    8   10   40     LCM  120
   71         3    4    9   10   12   15   18     LCM  180
   71         3    5    6   10   12   15   20     LCM  60
   73         3    5    6    9   12   18   20     LCM  180
   74         2    5    9   10   18   30     LCM  90
   74         3    4    6    7   12   42     LCM  84
   75         3    4    5    8   15   40     LCM  120
   76         2    4    6   16   48     LCM  48
   76         2    5    7   14   20   28     LCM  140
   76         3    4    8   10   12   15   24     LCM  120
   78         2    6    8   10   12   40     LCM  120
   78         3    4    5    9   12   45     LCM  180
   78         3    4    8    9   12   18   24     LCM  72
   78         3    5    6    8   12   20   24     LCM  120
   79         2    3   10   24   40     LCM  120
   79         2    5    8   10   24   30     LCM  120
   80         2    4   10   15   21   28     LCM  420
   81         2    3   12   16   48     LCM  48
   81         2    4   10   15   20   30     LCM  60
   81         3    4    5    7   20   42     LCM  420
   81         3    4    7   10   14   15   28     LCM  420
   81         3    5    6    9   10   18   30     LCM  90
   82         2    4   12   14   15   35     LCM  420
   82         2    4    9   18   21   28     LCM  252
   82         2    5    6   20   21   28     LCM  420
   82         2    5    8   12   15   40     LCM  120
   82         2    6    7   10   15   42     LCM  210
   83         2    4    9   18   20   30     LCM  180
   83         3    4    7    9   14   18   28     LCM  252
   83         3    5    6    7   14   20   28     LCM  420
   84         2    4   11   12   22   33     LCM  132
   84         2    6    7    9   18   42     LCM  126
   85         2    4   10   14   20   35     LCM  140
   85         2    4   10   15   18   36     LCM  180
   85         2    5    8   10   20   40     LCM  40
   86         2    5    9   10   15   45     LCM  90
   86         2    8    9   10   15   18   24     LCM  360
   86         3    5    6    8   10   24   30     LCM  120
   87         2    4    6   15   60     LCM  60
   87         2    4    8   21   24   28     LCM  168
   87         2    5    6   18   20   36     LCM  180
   87         3    4    6   10   15   21   28     LCM  420
   87         4    5    6    9   10   15   18   20     LCM  180
   88         2    4    8   20   24   30     LCM  120
   88         2    5    7   12   20   42     LCM  420
   88         2    7   10   12   14   15   28     LCM  420
   88         3    4    6   10   15   20   30     LCM  60
   88         3    4    7    8   14   24   28     LCM  168
   89         2    3    9   30   45     LCM  90
   89         2    6    7    8   24   42     LCM  168
   89         3    4    6   12   14   15   35     LCM  420
   89         3    4    6    9   18   21   28     LCM  252
   89         3    5    6    8   12   15   40     LCM  120
   90         2    7    9   12   14   18   28     LCM  252
   90         3    4    6    9   18   20   30     LCM  180
   91         3    4    6   11   12   22   33     LCM  132
   92         2    3   12   15   60     LCM  60
   92         2    4   10   12   24   40     LCM  120
   92         2    4    5   36   45     LCM  180
   92         2    4    8   18   24   36     LCM  72
   92         2    5    6   14   30   35     LCM  210
   92         2    5    6   15   24   40     LCM  120
   92         3    4    6   10   14   20   35     LCM  420
   92         3    4    6   10   15   18   36     LCM  180
   92         3    4    8    9   10   18   40     LCM  360
   92         3    5    6    8   10   20   40     LCM  120
   92         3    5    9   10   12   15   18   20     LCM  180
   92         4    5    6    8   10   15   20   24     LCM  120
   93         2    5    8    9   24   45     LCM  360
   93         3    4    5   12   20   21   28     LCM  420
   93         3    4    7   10   12   15   42     LCM  420
   93         3    5    6    9   10   15   45     LCM  90
   93         3    6    8    9   10   15   18   24     LCM  360
   94         2    6   10   12   15   21   28     LCM  420
   94         3    4    6    8   21   24   28     LCM  168
   94         4    5    6    8    9   18   20   24     LCM  360
   94         4    5    6    9   10   12   18   30     LCM  180
   95         2    3   10   20   60     LCM  60
   95         2    3    9   27   54     LCM  54
   95         2    4   10   15   16   48     LCM  240
   95         2    4    8    9   72     LCM  72
   95         2    4    9   15   20   45     LCM  180
   95         2    6   10   12   15   20   30     LCM  60
   95         2    7    8   12   14   24   28     LCM  168
   95         3    4    6    8   20   24   30     LCM  120
   95         3    4    7    9   12   18   42     LCM  252
   95         3    5    6    7   12   20   42     LCM  420
   95         3    6    7   10   12   14   15   28     LCM  420
   96         2    5    7   10   30   42     LCM  210
   96         2    6    9   12   18   21   28     LCM  252
   96         3    4    5   14   15   20   35     LCM  420
   96         4    5    6    7   12   14   20   28     LCM  420
   97         2    4    9   16   18   48     LCM  144
   97         2    5    6   16   20   48     LCM  240
   97         2    6    9   12   18   20   30     LCM  180
   97         3    5    8   10   12   15   20   24     LCM  120
   97         3    6    7    9   12   14   18   28     LCM  252
   98         3    4    5   11   20   22   33     LCM  660
   98         3    4    5   12   18   20   36     LCM  180
   99         2    4    8   15   30   40     LCM  120
   99         2    6   10   11   15   22   33     LCM  330
   99         2    6   10   12   14   20   35     LCM  420
   99         2    6   10   12   15   18   36     LCM  180
   99         2    6    9   14   15   18   35     LCM  630
   99         2    8    9   10   12   18   40     LCM  360
   99         3    4    5    6   36   45     LCM  180
   99         3    4    6   10   12   24   40     LCM  120
   99         3    4    6    8   18   24   36     LCM  72
   99         3    5    8    9   12   18   20   24     LCM  360
   99         4    5    6    8   10   12   24   30     LCM  120
  100         2    6    7    8   21   56     LCM  168
  100         3    4    7    8   12   24   42     LCM  168
  100         3    5    6    8    9   24   45     LCM  360
  101         2    4    5   30   60     LCM  60
  101         2    5   10   15   20   21   28     LCM  420
  101         2    6    8   12   21   24   28     LCM  168
  101         2    6    9   11   18   22   33     LCM  198
  101         3    4    5   10   21   28   30     LCM  420
  102         2    4    8   16   24   48     LCM  48
  102         2    4    9   12   30   45     LCM  180
  102         2    6    8   12   20   24   30     LCM  120
  102         3    4    6   10   15   16   48     LCM  240
  102         3    4    6    8    9   72     LCM  72
  102         3    4    6    9   15   20   45     LCM  180
  102         3    5    7   10   14   15   20   28     LCM  420
  102         3    6    7    8   12   14   24   28     LCM  168
  103         2    4    8   14   35   40     LCM  280
  103         2    5   12   14   15   20   35     LCM  420
  103         2    5    9   18   20   21   28     LCM  1260
  103         2    7    9   10   15   18   42     LCM  630
  103         3    4    5   12   14   30   35     LCM  420
  103         3    4    5   12   15   24   40     LCM  120
  103         3    5    6    7   10   30   42     LCM  210
  104         2    3   20   21   28   30     LCM  420
  104         2    4    7   21   28   42     LCM  84
  104         2    6    8   14   15   24   35     LCM  840
  104         3    4    6    9   16   18   48     LCM  144
  104         3    5    7    9   14   18   20   28     LCM  1260
  104         4    5    6    7   10   14   28   30     LCM  420
  105         2    4    7   20   30   42     LCM  420
  105         2    5   11   12   20   22   33     LCM  660
  105         4    5    6    8   10   12   20   40     LCM  120
  105         4    5    6    8    9   15   18   40     LCM  360
  106         2    5   10   15   18   20   36     LCM  180
  106         2    5    6   12   36   45     LCM  180
  106         2    6    8   11   22   24   33     LCM  264
  106         2    6    8   12   18   24   36     LCM  72
  106         3    4    5   10   18   30   36     LCM  180
  106         3    4    5   10   20   24   40     LCM  120
  106         3    4    6    8   15   30   40     LCM  120
  106         3    6    8    9   10   12   18   40     LCM  360
  106         4    5    6    9   10   12   15   45     LCM  180
  106         4    6    8    9   10   12   15   18   24     LCM  360
  107         2    6    7   14   20   28   30     LCM  420
  107         3    5    8    9   10   18   24   30     LCM  360
  108         2    3   18   21   28   36     LCM  252
  108         2    4   10   12   20   60     LCM  60
  108         2    4    9   12   27   54     LCM  108
  108         2    4    9   15   18   60     LCM  180
  108         2    5   10   12   21   28   30     LCM  420
  108         2    5    6   15   20   60     LCM  60
  108         2    5    8   20   21   24   28     LCM  840
  108         2    7    8   10   15   24   42     LCM  840
  108         3    4    5   12   16   20   48     LCM  240
  108         3    4    5    6   30   60     LCM  60
  108         3    4    9   10   15   18   21   28     LCM  1260
  108         3    5    6   10   15   20   21   28     LCM  420
  109         2    3   18   20   30   36     LCM  180
  109         2    4    5   28   70     LCM  140
  109         2    4    7   18   36   42     LCM  252
  109         2    6   10   12   15   16   48     LCM  240
  109         2    6    8    9   12   72     LCM  72
  109         2    6    9   10   18   24   40     LCM  360
  109         2    6    9   12   15   20   45     LCM  180
  109         2    7    8   10   14   28   40     LCM  280
  109         3    4    6    8   16   24   48     LCM  48
  109         3    4    6    9   12   30   45     LCM  180
  109         3    4    9   10   15   18   20   30     LCM  180
  109         3    5    7   10   12   14   28   30     LCM  420
  109         3    5    7    8   14   20   24   28     LCM  840
  109         4    5    6    7   10   15   20   42     LCM  420
  110         2    3    9   24   72     LCM  72
  110         2    4    6   14   84     LCM  84
  110         2    5    7    9   42   45     LCM  630
  110         2    7    8    9   18   24   42     LCM  504
  110         3    4   10   11   12   15   22   33     LCM  660
  110         3    4    6    8   14   35   40     LCM  840
  110         3    4    9   12   14   15   18   35     LCM  1260
  110         3    5    6   12   14   15   20   35     LCM  420
  110         3    5    6    9   18   20   21   28     LCM  1260
  110         3    5    8    9   12   15   18   40     LCM  360
  110         3    6    7    9   10   15   18   42     LCM  630
```

I had the numbers pushed close together with commas, then added up the LCM divided by each number. Seems to have come out perfectly, the sum should be the same as the LCM. I had to stop at 106, too many characters total otherwise.

```
   11         2,3,6     LCM  6         3+2+1=6
   24         2,4,6,12     LCM  12         6+3+2+1=12
   30         2,3,10,15     LCM  30        15+10+3+2=30
   31         2,4,5,20     LCM  20        10+5+4+1=20
   32         2,3,9,18     LCM  18         9+6+2+1=18
   37         2,3,8,24     LCM  24        12+8+3+1=24
   38         3,4,5,6,20     LCM  60        20+15+12+10+3=60
   43         2,4,10,12,15     LCM  60        30+15+6+5+4=60
   45         2,4,9,12,18     LCM  36        18+9+4+3+2=36
   45         2,5,6,12,20     LCM  60        30+12+10+5+3=60
   50         2,4,8,12,24     LCM  24        12+6+3+2+1=24
   50         3,4,6,10,12,15     LCM  60        20+15+10+6+5+4=60
   52         3,4,6,9,12,18     LCM  36        12+9+6+4+3+2=36
   53         2,5,6,10,30     LCM  30        15+6+5+3+1=30
   54         2,3,7,42     LCM  42        21+14+6+1=42
   55         2,4,7,14,28     LCM  28        14+7+4+2+1=28
   57         3,4,5,10,15,20     LCM  60        20+15+12+6+4+3=60
   57         3,4,6,8,12,24     LCM  24         8+6+4+3+2+1=24
   59         3,4,5,9,18,20     LCM  180        60+45+36+20+10+9=180
   60         2,6,9,10,15,18     LCM  90        45+15+10+9+6+5=90
   61         2,4,6,21,28     LCM  84        42+21+14+4+3=84
   62         2,4,6,20,30     LCM  60        30+15+10+3+2=60
   62         3,4,6,7,14,28     LCM  84        28+21+14+12+6+3=84
   64         2,4,8,10,40     LCM  40        20+10+5+4+1=40
   64         2,5,10,12,15,20     LCM  60        30+12+6+5+4+3=60
   64         3,4,5,10,12,30     LCM  60        20+15+12+6+5+2=60
   64         3,4,5,8,20,24     LCM  120        40+30+24+15+6+5=120
   65         2,6,8,10,15,24     LCM  120        60+20+15+12+8+5=120
   66         2,3,12,21,28     LCM  84        42+28+7+4+3=84
   66         2,4,6,18,36     LCM  36        18+9+6+2+1=36
   66         2,5,9,12,18,20     LCM  180        90+36+20+15+10+9=180
   67         2,3,12,20,30     LCM  60        30+20+5+3+2=60
   67         2,4,7,12,42     LCM  84        42+21+12+7+2=84
   67         2,5,6,9,45     LCM  90        45+18+15+10+2=90
   67         2,6,8,9,18,24     LCM  72        36+12+9+8+4+3=72
   69         2,3,14,15,35     LCM  210       105+70+15+14+6=210
   69         2,6,7,12,14,28     LCM  84        42+14+12+7+6+3=84
   71         2,3,11,22,33     LCM  66        33+22+6+3+2=66
   71         2,3,12,18,36     LCM  36        18+12+3+2+1=36
   71         2,5,8,12,20,24     LCM  120        60+24+15+10+6+5=120
   71         3,4,6,8,10,40     LCM  120        40+30+20+15+12+3=120
   71         3,4,9,10,12,15,18     LCM  180        60+45+20+18+15+12+10=180
   71         3,5,6,10,12,15,20     LCM  60        20+12+10+6+5+4+3=60
   73         3,5,6,9,12,18,20     LCM  180        60+36+30+20+15+10+9=180
   74         2,5,9,10,18,30     LCM  90        45+18+10+9+5+3=90
   74         3,4,6,7,12,42     LCM  84        28+21+14+12+7+2=84
   75         3,4,5,8,15,40     LCM  120        40+30+24+15+8+3=120
   76         2,4,6,16,48     LCM  48        24+12+8+3+1=48
   76         2,5,7,14,20,28     LCM  140        70+28+20+10+7+5=140
   76         3,4,8,10,12,15,24     LCM  120        40+30+15+12+10+8+5=120
   78         2,6,8,10,12,40     LCM  120        60+20+15+12+10+3=120
   78         3,4,5,9,12,45     LCM  180        60+45+36+20+15+4=180
   78         3,4,8,9,12,18,24     LCM  72        24+18+9+8+6+4+3=72
   78         3,5,6,8,12,20,24     LCM  120        40+24+20+15+10+6+5=120
   79         2,3,10,24,40     LCM  120        60+40+12+5+3=120
   79         2,5,8,10,24,30     LCM  120        60+24+15+12+5+4=120
   80         2,4,10,15,21,28     LCM  420       210+105+42+28+20+15=420
   81         2,3,12,16,48     LCM  48        24+16+4+3+1=48
   81         2,4,10,15,20,30     LCM  60        30+15+6+4+3+2=60
   81         3,4,5,7,20,42     LCM  420       140+105+84+60+21+10=420
   81         3,4,7,10,14,15,28     LCM  420       140+105+60+42+30+28+15=420
   81         3,5,6,9,10,18,30     LCM  90        30+18+15+10+9+5+3=90
   82         2,4,12,14,15,35     LCM  420       210+105+35+30+28+12=420
   82         2,4,9,18,21,28     LCM  252       126+63+28+14+12+9=252
   82         2,5,6,20,21,28     LCM  420       210+84+70+21+20+15=420
   82         2,5,8,12,15,40     LCM  120        60+24+15+10+8+3=120
   82         2,6,7,10,15,42     LCM  210       105+35+30+21+14+5=210
   83         2,4,9,18,20,30     LCM  180        90+45+20+10+9+6=180
   83         3,4,7,9,14,18,28     LCM  252        84+63+36+28+18+14+9=252
   83         3,5,6,7,14,20,28     LCM  420       140+84+70+60+30+21+15=420
   84         2,4,11,12,22,33     LCM  132        66+33+12+11+6+4=132
   84         2,6,7,9,18,42     LCM  126        63+21+18+14+7+3=126
   85         2,4,10,14,20,35     LCM  140        70+35+14+10+7+4=140
   85         2,4,10,15,18,36     LCM  180        90+45+18+12+10+5=180
   85         2,5,8,10,20,40     LCM  40        20+8+5+4+2+1=40
   86         2,5,9,10,15,45     LCM  90        45+18+10+9+6+2=90
   86         2,8,9,10,15,18,24     LCM  360       180+45+40+36+24+20+15=360
   86         3,5,6,8,10,24,30     LCM  120        40+24+20+15+12+5+4=120
   87         2,4,6,15,60     LCM  60        30+15+10+4+1=60
   87         2,4,8,21,24,28     LCM  168        84+42+21+8+7+6=168
   87         2,5,6,18,20,36     LCM  180        90+36+30+10+9+5=180
   87         3,4,6,10,15,21,28     LCM  420       140+105+70+42+28+20+15=420
   87         4,5,6,9,10,15,18,20     LCM  180        45+36+30+20+18+12+10+9=180
   88         2,4,8,20,24,30     LCM  120        60+30+15+6+5+4=120
   88         2,5,7,12,20,42     LCM  420       210+84+60+35+21+10=420
   88         2,7,10,12,14,15,28     LCM  420       210+60+42+35+30+28+15=420
   88         3,4,6,10,15,20,30     LCM  60        20+15+10+6+4+3+2=60
   88         3,4,7,8,14,24,28     LCM  168        56+42+24+21+12+7+6=168
   89         2,3,9,30,45     LCM  90        45+30+10+3+2=90
   89         2,6,7,8,24,42     LCM  168        84+28+24+21+7+4=168
   89         3,4,6,12,14,15,35     LCM  420       140+105+70+35+30+28+12=420
   89         3,4,6,9,18,21,28     LCM  252        84+63+42+28+14+12+9=252
   89         3,5,6,8,12,15,40     LCM  120        40+24+20+15+10+8+3=120
   90         2,7,9,12,14,18,28     LCM  252       126+36+28+21+18+14+9=252
   90         3,4,6,9,18,20,30     LCM  180        60+45+30+20+10+9+6=180
   91         3,4,6,11,12,22,33     LCM  132        44+33+22+12+11+6+4=132
   92         2,3,12,15,60     LCM  60        30+20+5+4+1=60
   92         2,4,10,12,24,40     LCM  120        60+30+12+10+5+3=120
   92         2,4,5,36,45     LCM  180        90+45+36+5+4=180
   92         2,4,8,18,24,36     LCM  72        36+18+9+4+3+2=72
   92         2,5,6,14,30,35     LCM  210       105+42+35+15+7+6=210
   92         2,5,6,15,24,40     LCM  120        60+24+20+8+5+3=120
   92         3,4,6,10,14,20,35     LCM  420       140+105+70+42+30+21+12=420
   92         3,4,6,10,15,18,36     LCM  180        60+45+30+18+12+10+5=180
   92         3,4,8,9,10,18,40     LCM  360       120+90+45+40+36+20+9=360
   92         3,5,6,8,10,20,40     LCM  120        40+24+20+15+12+6+3=120
   92         3,5,9,10,12,15,18,20     LCM  180        60+36+20+18+15+12+10+9=180
   92         4,5,6,8,10,15,20,24     LCM  120        30+24+20+15+12+8+6+5=120
   93         2,5,8,9,24,45     LCM  360       180+72+45+40+15+8=360
   93         3,4,5,12,20,21,28     LCM  420       140+105+84+35+21+20+15=420
   93         3,4,7,10,12,15,42     LCM  420       140+105+60+42+35+28+10=420
   93         3,5,6,9,10,15,45     LCM  90        30+18+15+10+9+6+2=90
   93         3,6,8,9,10,15,18,24     LCM  360       120+60+45+40+36+24+20+15=360
   94         2,6,10,12,15,21,28     LCM  420       210+70+42+35+28+20+15=420
   94         3,4,6,8,21,24,28     LCM  168        56+42+28+21+8+7+6=168
   94         4,5,6,8,9,18,20,24     LCM  360        90+72+60+45+40+20+18+15=360
   94         4,5,6,9,10,12,18,30     LCM  180        45+36+30+20+18+15+10+6=180
   95         2,3,10,20,60     LCM  60        30+20+6+3+1=60
   95         2,3,9,27,54     LCM  54        27+18+6+2+1=54
   95         2,4,10,15,16,48     LCM  240       120+60+24+16+15+5=240
   95         2,4,8,9,72     LCM  72        36+18+9+8+1=72
   95         2,4,9,15,20,45     LCM  180        90+45+20+12+9+4=180
   95         2,6,10,12,15,20,30     LCM  60        30+10+6+5+4+3+2=60
   95         2,7,8,12,14,24,28     LCM  168        84+24+21+14+12+7+6=168
   95         3,4,6,8,20,24,30     LCM  120        40+30+20+15+6+5+4=120
   95         3,4,7,9,12,18,42     LCM  252        84+63+36+28+21+14+6=252
   95         3,5,6,7,12,20,42     LCM  420       140+84+70+60+35+21+10=420
   95         3,6,7,10,12,14,15,28     LCM  420       140+70+60+42+35+30+28+15=420
   96         2,5,7,10,30,42     LCM  210       105+42+30+21+7+5=210
   96         2,6,9,12,18,21,28     LCM  252       126+42+28+21+14+12+9=252
   96         3,4,5,14,15,20,35     LCM  420       140+105+84+30+28+21+12=420
   96         4,5,6,7,12,14,20,28     LCM  420       105+84+70+60+35+30+21+15=420
   97         2,4,9,16,18,48     LCM  144        72+36+16+9+8+3=144
   97         2,5,6,16,20,48     LCM  240       120+48+40+15+12+5=240
   97         2,6,9,12,18,20,30     LCM  180        90+30+20+15+10+9+6=180
   97         3,5,8,10,12,15,20,24     LCM  120        40+24+15+12+10+8+6+5=120
   97         3,6,7,9,12,14,18,28     LCM  252        84+42+36+28+21+18+14+9=252
   98         3,4,5,11,20,22,33     LCM  660       220+165+132+60+33+30+20=660
   98         3,4,5,12,18,20,36     LCM  180        60+45+36+15+10+9+5=180
   99         2,4,8,15,30,40     LCM  120        60+30+15+8+4+3=120
   99         2,6,10,11,15,22,33     LCM  330       165+55+33+30+22+15+10=330
   99         2,6,10,12,14,20,35     LCM  420       210+70+42+35+30+21+12=420
   99         2,6,10,12,15,18,36     LCM  180        90+30+18+15+12+10+5=180
   99         2,6,9,14,15,18,35     LCM  630       315+105+70+45+42+35+18=630
   99         2,8,9,10,12,18,40     LCM  360       180+45+40+36+30+20+9=360
   99         3,4,5,6,36,45     LCM  180        60+45+36+30+5+4=180
   99         3,4,6,10,12,24,40     LCM  120        40+30+20+12+10+5+3=120
   99         3,4,6,8,18,24,36     LCM  72        24+18+12+9+4+3+2=72
   99         3,5,8,9,12,18,20,24     LCM  360       120+72+45+40+30+20+18+15=360
   99         4,5,6,8,10,12,24,30     LCM  120        30+24+20+15+12+10+5+4=120
  100         2,6,7,8,21,56     LCM  168        84+28+24+21+8+3=168
  100         3,4,7,8,12,24,42     LCM  168        56+42+24+21+14+7+4=168
  100         3,5,6,8,9,24,45     LCM  360       120+72+60+45+40+15+8=360
  101         2,4,5,30,60     LCM  60        30+15+12+2+1=60
  101         2,5,10,15,20,21,28     LCM  420       210+84+42+28+21+20+15=420
  101         2,6,8,12,21,24,28     LCM  168        84+28+21+14+8+7+6=168
  101         2,6,9,11,18,22,33     LCM  198        99+33+22+18+11+9+6=198
  101         3,4,5,10,21,28,30     LCM  420       140+105+84+42+20+15+14=420
  102         2,4,8,16,24,48     LCM  48        24+12+6+3+2+1=48
  102         2,4,9,12,30,45     LCM  180        90+45+20+15+6+4=180
  102         2,6,8,12,20,24,30     LCM  120        60+20+15+10+6+5+4=120
  102         3,4,6,10,15,16,48     LCM  240        80+60+40+24+16+15+5=240
  102         3,4,6,8,9,72     LCM  72        24+18+12+9+8+1=72
  102         3,4,6,9,15,20,45     LCM  180        60+45+30+20+12+9+4=180
  102         3,5,7,10,14,15,20,28     LCM  420       140+84+60+42+30+28+21+15=420
  102         3,6,7,8,12,14,24,28     LCM  168        56+28+24+21+14+12+7+6=168
  103         2,4,8,14,35,40     LCM  280       140+70+35+20+8+7=280
  103         2,5,12,14,15,20,35     LCM  420       210+84+35+30+28+21+12=420
  103         2,5,9,18,20,21,28     LCM  1260       630+252+140+70+63+60+45=1260
  103         2,7,9,10,15,18,42     LCM  630       315+90+70+63+42+35+15=630
  103         3,4,5,12,14,30,35     LCM  420       140+105+84+35+30+14+12=420
  103         3,4,5,12,15,24,40     LCM  120        40+30+24+10+8+5+3=120
  103         3,5,6,7,10,30,42     LCM  210        70+42+35+30+21+7+5=210
  104         2,3,20,21,28,30     LCM  420       210+140+21+20+15+14=420
  104         2,4,7,21,28,42     LCM  84        42+21+12+4+3+2=84
  104         2,6,8,14,15,24,35     LCM  840       420+140+105+60+56+35+24=840
  104         3,4,6,9,16,18,48     LCM  144        48+36+24+16+9+8+3=144
  104         3,5,7,9,14,18,20,28     LCM  1260       420+252+180+140+90+70+63+45=1260
  104         4,5,6,7,10,14,28,30     LCM  420       105+84+70+60+42+30+15+14=420
  105         2,4,7,20,30,42     LCM  420       210+105+60+21+14+10=420
  105         2,5,11,12,20,22,33     LCM  660       330+132+60+55+33+30+20=660
  105         4,5,6,8,10,12,20,40     LCM  120        30+24+20+15+12+10+6+3=120
  105         4,5,6,8,9,15,18,40     LCM  360        90+72+60+45+40+24+20+9=360
  106         2,5,10,15,18,20,36     LCM  180        90+36+18+12+10+9+5=180
  106         2,5,6,12,36,45     LCM  180        90+36+30+15+5+4=180
  106         2,6,8,11,22,24,33     LCM  264       132+44+33+24+12+11+8=264
  106         2,6,8,12,18,24,36     LCM  72        36+12+9+6+4+3+2=72
  106         3,4,5,10,18,30,36     LCM  180        60+45+36+18+10+6+5=180
  106         3,4,5,10,20,24,40     LCM  120        40+30+24+12+6+5+3=120
  106         3,4,6,8,15,30,40     LCM  120        40+30+20+15+8+4+3=120
  106         3,6,8,9,10,12,18,40     LCM  360       120+60+45+40+36+30+20+9=360
  106         4,5,6,9,10,12,15,45     LCM  180        45+36+30+20+18+15+12+4=180
  106         4,6,8,9,10,12,15,18,24     LCM  360        90+60+45+40+36+30+24+20+15=360
```

Comment: Please label the columns here.

Answer (score 5):

Greg Egan has verified, using Mathematica, that $77$ cannot be written as the sum of distinct positive integers whose reciprocals sum to $1$:

https://twitter.com/gregeganSF/status/1156839799610675200.

Christopher D. Long proved it using Sage; his code is here:

https://github.com/octonion/puzzles/tree/master/twitter/lehmer.

Dima Pasechnik wrote a very elegant Sage program that proves this result:

```
sage: from builtins import sum as psum
sage: def sumreseq1(l):
....:     return 1==psum(map(lambda t: 1/t, l)) 
sage: filter(sumreseq1, Partitions(11,max_slope=-1))
[[6, 3, 2]]
sage: filter(sumreseq1, Partitions(77,max_slope=-1))
[]
```

There are $58499$ ways to write $77$ as a sum of distinct positive integers, and one only needs to check these to prove the result.

Here, by the way, is the complete list of positive integers that cannot be written as the sum of distinct positive integers whose reciprocals sum to 1:

> $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 34, 35, 36, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 56, 58, 63, 68, 70, 72, 77$

This is [$A051882$](http://oeis.org/A051882) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.  However, I don't believe there is a reference to a proof.  Luckily, Mr. Drake has written a [program that verifies this list](https://repl.it/@MrDrake/A051882).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt at a human-readable proof. Let such a partition be $X = \{ x_i \}, 1 \leq i \leq n$. Note that by modular considerations there cannot be a prime $p$ that only divides a single $x_i$. In particular, this implies that the largest such prime must satisfy $p + 2\cdot p <= 77$, and hence $p \leq 23$. But more is true; if $ Y = \{ p\cdot y_i \}, 1 \leq i \leq m$, are the terms of $X$ divisible by $p$, then $ \sum_{i=1}^{m} y/y_i \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where $ y = \prod_{i=1}^{m} y_i$. This rapidly eliminates $p > 11$.

Now $p=11$ is only slightly harder; the only candidate for $Y$ is $\{ 1\cdot 11,2\cdot 11,3\cdot 11 \}$, but this only leaves $77-6\cdot 11 = 11$ for the sum of the remaining terms of our partition. Now, the remaining terms can only be products of $2$ and $3$, leaving the only candidate for the remaining terms $\{ 2,3,6 \}$, but $1/2+1/3+1/6 = 1$ is too big. Thus the largest possible prime factor dividing an $x_i$ is 7.

The above argument also works for prime powers, showing that $3^2$ is the largest squared prime factor that may occur and any higher power must be a power of $2$. With some more work, you get a list of candidate $Y$ if $7$ divides some $x_i$ e.g. $Y = \{ 7, 42 \}, \{ 14, 35 \}, \{ 21, 28 \}$ or $Y = \{ 7, 14, 28\}$.

This should reduce the possible $X$ to a list checkable by hand.